# CesiumJS memory management issues

Tags: javascript, json, geojson, cesiumjs

I am making a 3d model viwer in cesiumjs. The geojson is requested from the url and it works fine for small models. Incase of complex json multipolygon files and json url request data exceeds 16mb cesium takes so long in parsing and then rendering and if I make a call to one other model it crashes the web browser with error out of memory. I checked chrome along side and it eats up around 900 memory for a 16mb geojson from url. Is there better way of memory management? or any tips how to tackle this problem. One solution could be 3d mesh simplification before sending the geojson for that model but I am asking related to memory management on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that part of the time is the browser running JSON.parse on a 16 megabyte file.  This is a synchronous operation in all browsers and there's nothing anyone can do about it until the browsers add asynchronous JSON parsing.  The first thing I would recommend is that you run your GeoJSON through [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) on the server, which should provide significant size savings.  This will decrease both the transmission time and JSON.parse time.  I would also be sure that your server is compressing your data, which will add further savings.  I have seen 16MB files go down to under a meg with these techniques.

That being said, that's only the first part of the problem.  The real question is not how big the GeoJSON is but how many features does it have?  If it's a 16MB file with ~15000 features, than my above suggestion will solve your problem.  If it has 10s of thousands of features, then you are going to run into some problems that are not easily solved.  I actually provided some details about this on our mailing list yesterday: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/F6IkY9aEG1I/8dRkhlBnLI4J

We're always looking for ways to optimize and further improve Cesium.  Feel free to reach out to our mailing list and provide some of your large sample data if you can, then we can use it as a good use case when we optimize things in the future.

Comment: Google earth web api KML handles the same data very smoothly and never ran out of memory so as the google earth is dying so we have to shift to Cesium and yeah it is way faster than google earth web plugin it takes time for loading but when the data is loaded its smoother than google earth but the good thing about google earth was that I could handle much more kml even of size 96mb and many more such files at same time but its slower. Sure I will participate in the mailing list!! Thanks I will explore the TopoJSON

Comment: btw where can I share the information on that group?

Comment: Google Earth is a native C++ application (which is why it requires a plugin) and makes it easier to brute force large data sets.  Since Cesium is pure JavaScript it makes having good performance much more challenging.  Don't get me wrong, Cesium has lots of room for optimization on load and we'll get there, it is just a much more difficult problem to solve.

Comment: You can post to the forum from either our website: http://cesiumjs.org/forum.html or from the main Google Groups page https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cesium-dev